# Replacing one images with another image using angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I want to replace the image on my online exam paper at the end of exam using AngularJs and html.

At starting exam ,I have already used **img id="online_start"** in my code where I used **css** to get the image into my page.

CSS:

```
  #online_start{
    background-image:url("start_exam.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:400px;
    height:150px;
    }
```

Now I want to replace that image at the end of the exam with another image using AngularJs.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UFT-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $compile, $window, $interval, $timeout, $filter) {

  $scope.pos = 0, $scope.correct = 0, $scope.ques = true;

  $scope.questions = [
    ["Which of the following a is not a keyword in Java ?", "class", "interface", "extends", "C"],

    ["Which of the following is an interface ?", "Thread", "Date", "Calender", "A"],

    ["Which company released Java Version 8 ?", "Sun", "Oracle", "Adobe", "A"],

    ["What is the length of Java datatype int ?", "32 bit", "16 bit", "None", "C"],

    ["What is the default value of Java datatype boolean?", "true", "false", "0", "A"]
  ];
  $scope.totalsecoriginal = $scope.totalsec = 60;
  $scope.totalsec--;
  $scope.min = parseInt($scope.totalsec / 60, 10);
  $scope.sec = $scope.totalsec - ($scope.min * 60);
  $scope.date = new Date();
  $scope.hhmmss = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss a');
  $scope.currentTime = new Date();
  $scope.currentTime.setSeconds($scope.currentTime.getSeconds() + 60);
  function _(x) {
    console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById(x)));
    return angular.element(document.getElementById(x))[0];
  }
  $scope.interval = $interval(function() {
    if ($scope.sec === 0) {
      $scope.min--;
      $scope.sec = 60;
    }
    $scope.sec--;
  }, 1000);
  $scope.$watch('sec', function() {
    if ($scope.min === 0 && $scope.sec === 0) {
      $interval.cancel($scope.interval);
      window.alert('Time Up!!!');
      $scope.pos = $scope.questions.length;
      $scope.temp = true;
      $scope.renderQuestion();
    }
  })
  $scope.renderQuestion = function() {
    if ($scope.pos >= $scope.questions.length) {
    $scope.myBackgroundUrl = 'url(animatedthankyou.gif)';

      $scope.ques = false;
      if (!$scope.temp) { $scope.temp = false;
        $interval.cancel($scope.interval);
      }
      $scope.showscore = Math.round($scope.correct / $scope.questions.length * 100);
      $scope.minuteleft = parseInt(($scope.totalsecoriginal - $scope.totalsec) / 60, 10);

      $scope.pos = 0;
      return false;
    }
    $scope.question = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][0];
    $scope.chA = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][1];
    $scope.chB = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][2];
    $scope.chC = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][3];
  }
  $scope.checkAnswer = function() {
    $scope.choices = angular.element(document.getElementsByName('choices'));
    $scope.choice = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.choices.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.choices[i].checked) {
        $scope.choice = $scope.choices[i].value;
        $scope.choices[i].checked = false;
      }
    }
    if ($scope.choice == $scope.questions[$scope.pos][4]) {
      $scope.correct++;
    }
    $scope.pos++;
    $scope.renderQuestion();
  }
  $scope.renderQuestion();

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Holder">
    <div id="Header"></div>
    <div id="NavBar">
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Loginpage.htm"> Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="Registrationpage.htm">Registration</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Content">
      <div id="PageHeading">
        <h1><marquee direction="right" behavior="alternate">All the Best</marquee></h1>
      </div>
      <div id="ContentLeft">
        <h2></h2>
        <br>
        <img id="online_start" ng-style="{background-image: myBackgroundUrl}">
        <br>
        <h6>Online Examination System(OES) is a Multiple Choice Questions(MCQ) based 
examination system that provides an easy to use environment for both 
Test Conducters and Students appearing for Examination.</h6>
      </div>
      <div id="ContentRight">
        <section class="loginform_cf">
          <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="StartTimer()">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td id="test_status" style="text-align:left">
                  <h3 ng-show='ques'>Question {{pos+1}} of {{questions.length}}</h3>
                  <h3 ng-hide='ques'>Test Completed  </h3>
                </td>
                <td ng-show='ques'> Exam Starts :<span ng-bind="hhmmss">  </span> </td>
                <td ng-show='ques'> Exam Ends : {{currentTime | date:'hh:mm:ss a'}} </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="test" colspan="3">
                  <div ng-show="ques">
                    <h3>{{question}}</h3>
                    <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>{{chA}}
                    <br>
                    <input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'>{{chB}}
                    <br>
                    <input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'>{{chC}}
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button ng-click='checkAnswer()'>Next</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            Your Left Time is :{{min}} Minutes {{sec}} Seconds
                  </div>
                  <div ng-hide='ques'>
     <h3>You got {{correct}} correct of {{questions.length}} questions</h3>
     <h3> Your Grade :  {{showscore}}% </h3>
     <h4>Exam Finished in Time :{{minuteleft}} Minutes {{sec}} Seconds</h4>
     <button ng-click='EndExam()'>End the Exam</button>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In CSS u are placing an `background-image`, and in JS u are placing a `src`!

Comment: Instead it should be `document.getElementById("online_start").style.backgroundImage = "animatedthankyou.gif";`

Comment: The whole business login you have written in JavaScript.Why you need  Angular? Its wastage of time.First bring the business in Angular then it may help to do some angular stuff.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.  If you want to delete it, there is a separate button for that.  But you are really wasting other people's time if you don't stand for what you posted, and don't upvote or accept any of the answers people posted to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS u are placing an `background-image`, and in JS u are placing a `src`!

instead replace

```
document.getElementById("online_start").src = "animatedthankyou.gif";
```

with

```
document.getElementById("online_start").style.backgroundImag‌​e = "animatedthankyou.gif";
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS it's not only a way to use fancy repeaters or magic double bindings, it allows to clean up your JS code by NOT doing DOM manipulation in your controllers (wich you are doing).

You can do more with less. Sse ng-style to change programatically your background image url:

```
<img id="online_start" ng-style="{background-image: myBackgroundUrl}">
```

and in your controller, change the background when you need:

```
if(pos >= questions.length){
    $scope.myBackgroundUrl = 'url(animatedthankyou.gif)';
}
```

Much cleaner, isn't it?

Comment: I have try it but its not working to replacing the images

Comment: that sounds strange, can you please provide a plunker or some more code?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $scope.myBackgroundUrl = {'background-image': 'url(animatedthankyou.gif)'};
```

And in HTML put the below line inside the div with ng-controller:

```
    <img id="online_start" ng-style="myBackgroundUrl">
```

See:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UFT-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $compile, $window, $interval, $timeout, $filter) {

  $scope.pos = 0, $scope.correct = 0, $scope.ques = true;

  $scope.questions = [
    ["Which of the following a is not a keyword in Java ?", "class", "interface", "extends", "C"],

    ["Which of the following is an interface ?", "Thread", "Date", "Calender", "A"],

    ["Which company released Java Version 8 ?", "Sun", "Oracle", "Adobe", "A"],

    ["What is the length of Java datatype int ?", "32 bit", "16 bit", "None", "C"],

    ["What is the default value of Java datatype boolean?", "true", "false", "0", "A"]
  ];
  $scope.totalsecoriginal = $scope.totalsec = 60;
  $scope.totalsec--;
  $scope.min = parseInt($scope.totalsec / 60, 10);
  $scope.sec = $scope.totalsec - ($scope.min * 60);
  $scope.date = new Date();
  $scope.hhmmss = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss a');
  $scope.currentTime = new Date();
  $scope.currentTime.setSeconds($scope.currentTime.getSeconds() + 60);
  function _(x) {
    console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById(x)));
    return angular.element(document.getElementById(x))[0];
  }
  $scope.interval = $interval(function() {
    if ($scope.sec === 0) {
      $scope.min--;
      $scope.sec = 60;
    }
    $scope.sec--;
  }, 1000);
  $scope.$watch('sec', function() {
    if ($scope.min === 0 && $scope.sec === 0) {
      $interval.cancel($scope.interval);
      window.alert('Time Up!!!');
      $scope.pos = $scope.questions.length;
      $scope.temp = true;
      $scope.renderQuestion();
    }
  })
  $scope.renderQuestion = function() {
    if ($scope.pos >= $scope.questions.length) {
    $scope.myBackgroundUrl = {'background-image': 'url(animatedthankyou.gif)'};


      $scope.ques = false;
      if (!$scope.temp) { $scope.temp = false;
        $interval.cancel($scope.interval);
      }
      $scope.showscore = Math.round($scope.correct / $scope.questions.length * 100);
      $scope.minuteleft = parseInt(($scope.totalsecoriginal - $scope.totalsec) / 60, 10);

      $scope.pos = 0;
      return false;
    }
    $scope.question = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][0];
    $scope.chA = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][1];
    $scope.chB = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][2];
    $scope.chC = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][3];
  }
  $scope.checkAnswer = function() {
    $scope.choices = angular.element(document.getElementsByName('choices'));
    $scope.choice = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.choices.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.choices[i].checked) {
        $scope.choice = $scope.choices[i].value;
        $scope.choices[i].checked = false;
      }
    }
    if ($scope.choice == $scope.questions[$scope.pos][4]) {
      $scope.correct++;
    }
    $scope.pos++;
    $scope.renderQuestion();
  }
  $scope.renderQuestion();

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Holder">
    <div id="Header"></div>
    <div id="NavBar">
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Loginpage.htm"> Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="Registrationpage.htm">Registration</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Content">
      <div id="PageHeading">
        <h1><marquee direction="right" behavior="alternate">All the Best</marquee></h1>
      </div>
      <div id="ContentLeft">
        <h2></h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h6>Online Examination System(OES) is a Multiple Choice Questions(MCQ) based 
examination system that provides an easy to use environment for both 
Test Conducters and Students appearing for Examination.</h6>
      </div>
      <div id="ContentRight">
        <section class="loginform_cf">
          <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="StartTimer()">
<img id="online_start" ng-style="myBackgroundUrl">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td id="test_status" style="text-align:left">
                  <h3 ng-show='ques'>Question {{pos+1}} of {{questions.length}}</h3>
                  <h3 ng-hide='ques'>Test Completed  </h3>
                </td>
                <td ng-show='ques'> Exam Starts :<span ng-bind="hhmmss">  </span> </td>
                <td ng-show='ques'> Exam Ends : {{currentTime | date:'hh:mm:ss a'}} </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="test" colspan="3">
                  <div ng-show="ques">
                    <h3>{{question}}</h3>
                    <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>{{chA}}
                    <br>
                    <input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'>{{chB}}
                    <br>
                    <input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'>{{chC}}
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button ng-click='checkAnswer()'>Next</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            Your Left Time is :{{min}} Minutes {{sec}} Seconds
                  </div>
                  <div ng-hide='ques'>
     <h3>You got {{correct}} correct of {{questions.length}} questions</h3>
     <h3> Your Grade :  {{showscore}}% </h3>
     <h4>Exam Finished in Time :{{minuteleft}} Minutes {{sec}} Seconds</h4>
     <button ng-click='EndExam()'>End the Exam</button>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```